# using a session variable to pull extra data from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked around and i cannot seem to find the answer anywhere, if it exists at all.

I am trying to access a field in my table with the $_SESSION variable. With this i am hoping to look up the $user_id variable and match that up with the id in the members table (which is the same) and echo out the 'fname' field.

Here is the code i have for this bit:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo $user_id; //this check echo's out the number 2, which is correct.

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id == $user_id");
echo $result; //doesnt echo anything out

$fname = $result;
echo $fname;
```

This may be a rookie mistake on my part but any help on this would be really appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: Where is your database connection? Where is your error checking?

Comment: SQL doesn't use two `==` for comparison, just one `=`. But that won't fix it: you need to read a tutorial on querying the db with PHP, because its not as simple as you are *guessing* it is.

Comment: Just to second @developerwjk and whilst you're at it, learn how to do it properly, that is by using prepared statements with `mysqli` or `PDO`. Ditch the use of `mysql_` functions as they're becoming deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

A key SQL syntax error in your code is the lack of single quotes before an after $user_id :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '" . $user_id . "'");
```

If you don't quote the variable data SQL will interpret it as code, not data. Try it.